# How to access values of other json objects in single table of datatable library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am trying to display data and view/edit/delete buttons using datatables.

I am getting user data and permission using two objects like this:
[image: [screenshot]]

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "userid": "1",
            "username": "John",
            "email": "john@gmail.com",
            "userrole": "SYSTEM VENDOR",
            "isactive": "Y",
            "activationstat": "deactivate",
            "activationmsg": "Deactivate"
        }
    ],
    "perm": 
    {
        "read": "y",
        "edit": "y",
        "delete": "n"
    }
}
```

The button needs to be rendered for each row. Datatables code is as:

```
$('#dt-user').DataTable({
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ],
    ajax: baseURL + 'user/list-user-aj',
    columns: [
        {
            "data": "id",
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
            }
        },
        { data: 'username' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'userrole' },
        { data: 'isactive' }
    ],
    responsive: {
        details: false
    }
});
```

How can I access the "perm" JSON object for checking its values for displaying buttons for edit, delete, print etc?

Comment: please put the code in the post and not include it as screenshot.

Comment: Did you try to log in your console the other params of the columns callback? Like `console.log(data, type, row, meta)`? Maybe some of those fields could contain the information you need.

Comment: Yes, I did. I can only access user info (data).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: You will not be able to get "perm" object within datatables initialization code. Datatables initialization code only works with "data" array from JSON.

However, here are two possible solutions to your situation:

**Option 1:**
If the "perm" object is going to be common for all elements (users) in the "data" array in JSON, like follows:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "userid": "1",
        "username": "John",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "userrole": "SYSTEM VENDOR",
        "isactive": "Y",
        "activationstat": "deactivate",
        "activationmsg": "Deactivate"
    },
    {
        "userid": "2",
        "username": "John2",
        "email": "john2@gmail.com",
        "userrole": "SYSTEM VENDOR2",
        "isactive": "Y",
        "activationstat": "deactivate",
        "activationmsg": "Deactivate"
    }
    <!-- and maybe some more objects-->
   ],
  "perm": 
   {
    "read": "y",
    "edit": "y",
    "delete": "n"
   }
}
```

then you can access the perm object like below: (and that would be outside of Datatables definition)

```
var permissions;
userDatatable.on('xhr', function () {
    var json = userDatatable.ajax.json();
    var permissions = json.perm;

});
```

where userDatatable will be the global javascript variable when you initialize Datatables like below:

```
var userDatatable = $('#dt-user').DataTable({  //......and all your code
```

Then inside your columns definition, you can access perm object and render buttons like this:

```
 columns:[
    {
      data:null,
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
         if(perm.delete === 'y'){
             return "<button class='deleteButton'> Delete </button>";
         }
      }
    }
 ]
```

Make sure javascript variable "permissions" is global and visible to your Datatables initialization code. This will get you the Delete button, but you will have to write additional Javascript/JQuery code to trigger the Datatables Editor's AJAX call to delete the row; both at backend and from the grid.

**Option 2**: You could modify your server-side code to return JSON such that it will have permissions object within each element of the "data" array:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "userid": "1",
        "username": "John",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "userrole": "SYSTEM VENDOR",
        "isactive": "Y",
        "activationstat": "deactivate",
        "activationmsg": "Deactivate",
        "perm": 
          {
            "read": "y",
            "edit": "y",
            "delete": "n"
           }
    },
    {
        "userid": "2",
        "username": "John2",
        "email": "john2@gmail.com",
        "userrole": "SYSTEM VENDOR2",
        "isactive": "Y",
        "activationstat": "deactivate",
        "activationmsg": "Deactivate",
         "perm": 
           {
             "read": "y",
             "edit": "y",
             "delete": "n"
           }
    }
    <!-- and maybe some more objects-->
   ]
}
```

With this second option, you could access perm object within the "render" function using "row.perm.delete" property.

Hope this help!

Comment: In Option 1 before setting values in permission variables datatable must be initialized and code for rendering columns is also in initialization. In that case, there is a error "permission" variable is not declared. I declared permissions and userDatatable as global. (It works if I initialized table first, then initialize permissions, destroy table and then again initialize datatable).

Comment: You are correct. "permissions" variable would be available only after Datatables AJAX call completes.
There is also a way to keep your AJAX call separate from Datatables initialization code. So you make AJAX call first, store data in javascript object, then make the "data" portion of the javascript object available as data to Datatables via "data" option. This way you can avoid having to destroy table and reinitialize.

Comment: Monica L Thank you very much. It worked. (And also I have stopped using datatables). :))))